# Form submit button not passing name to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Probably a very simple answer but one I am struggling with. I have a basic form which has a standard submit button. When this is clicked, it is being valued by jquery serialize and then Ajax to process php page etc. I am confused as to why the name of my submit button 'submit' is not being posted when a user clicks on it. The only reason I can think of, is that serialize only handles text,text area and select elements. If so, how can I send the name through to php for processing. I have included some sample code and would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks

html form

```
<!--- Form to add box -->

<div id="boxaddform" style="display:none;">
    <div class="dialogTop_padd"></div>
        <form id="BA_boxform" name="BA_boxform" method="post">  

        <fieldset>
        <legend><span></span>Select Company</legend>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="formMessage">Click again to open</div>
        <div class="fld_fld">

        <div>
        <label for="BA_customer">Company:</label><br />
        <select name="BA_customer" id="BA_customer">
        <option SELECTED VALUE="">Select a Company</option>
        <?php
        do {  
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordsetcust['customer']?>"><?php echo $row_Recordsetcust['customer']?></option>
        <?php

        } 
        while ($row_Recordsetcust = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetcust));
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($Recordsetcust);

        if($rows > 0)

        {
        mysql_data_seek($Recordsetcust, 0);
        $row_Recordsetcust = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetcust);
        }

        ?>
        </select>

        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <!--- displays the address and dept from the change function -->
        <div id="BA_dept"></div>
        <br />
        <div id="BA_address"></div>

            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="dialogTop_padd"></div>
        <!--- fieldset for service level -->
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Service Level</legend>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div>
        <label for="BA_service">Service level:</label>
        <select name="BA_service" id="BA_service">
        <option SELECTED VALUE="">Select an option</option>
        <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
        <option value="Rapid">Rapid</option>
        </select><br />
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="dialogTop_padd"></div>

        <!--- fieldset for box # -->
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Box Details</legend>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div>
        <label for="BA_box">Box#:</label><br />
        <input id="BA_box" name="BA_box" type="text" size="32" maxlength="128"  /><br />
        </div>

        <div>
        <label for="BA_destdate">Destroy date:</label>
        <input id="BA_destdate" name="BA_destdate" type="text" size="32" maxlength="128" value = "" /><br />
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="dialogTop_padd"></div>
        <!--- fieldset for authorisation -->
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Authorisation</legend>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div>
        <label for="BA_authorised">Requested By:</label>
        <input id="BA_authorised" name="BA_authorised" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['kt_name_usr']; ?>"><br />
        </div>
        </fieldset>

        <!--- div to show callback result from ajax via dialog -->
            <br />      
            <div id="BA_addbox"></div>
            <br />
             <input class="AddBoxSubmitButton" type="submit"  id="submit" name="submit" value="Add Box" />
             <input class="AddBoxResetButton" type="reset"  name="cancel" value="Clear Form" />
        <!--- buttons to submit form and reset form to default status -->
        <!-- <button id="BA_submit" class="submitbutton icon-right ui-state-default2 ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span>Add Box</button>
        <button type="reset" id="BA_reset" class="resetbutton icon-right ui-state-default2 ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span>Reset</button>
        --><br />

        </form>
           <br />
    </div>
```

jquery code

```
$(function(){         
        $("#BA_boxform").submit(function(){

         var formdata = $('#BA_boxform').serialize();
         alert(formdata);
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/domain/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php",
           data: formdata,
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(msg){
               //$("#confirm_department").hide();

               /*
               var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
               .html('Your intake was successfully submitted and will be viewable in the reporting area.<br /><br />Thank you.');
               $dialog.dialog({
               autoOpen: true,
               modal: true,
               title: 'Box intake submission successfull',
               width: 400,
               height: 200,
               draggable: false,
               resizable: false,
               buttons: {
               Close: function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               }
               }
               });
               */
               //alert('You have succesfully submitted your ' + msg.company + ' report. Thank you.');
               //console.log(msg);
               $("#BA_addbox").show();

               //$("#formImage .col_1 li").show();
               $("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
               //$("#boxaddform").hide();
          }
       });
         return false;
     });
});

// End function to submit box intake form
```

cutdown php code for illustration

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))    { }
```

Comment: Which is `alert(formdata);` 's output?

Comment: @Ander2 all data is that is sent is in the alert apart from the submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said, submit buttons aren't serialized. A possible workaround: { not tested but as i understand it, should work }

```
$('#BA_boxform input:submit').on('click', function () {
    var formdata = $('#BA_boxform').serialize() + '&submit=' + $(this).val();
    //....
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @PLB what is DRY principle?

Comment: @PLB WOW I have learn't something new today. Thanks for heads up

Comment: @PLB could you explain what DRY principle has to do here?

Comment: @roasted Sure. If name of submit button changes, javascript should be updated as well. OP may omit submit button name in form but this may mess up things if javascript form submission will be disabled in future. Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

`jQuery` won't serialize submit button:

> [Docs:](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
>
> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button.

Workaround is to check if `$_POST` is not empty:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // Your code here
}
```

or check if specific input was set. E.g.

```
 if (isset($_POST['BA_customer'])) {

 }
```

Comment: But here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2 you see this: "If a form contains more than one submit button, only the activated submit button is successful."

Comment: @Cherniv — The submit button isn't activated. It is clicked. JavaScript runs. Its activation is cancelled by the JS.

Comment: @Cherniv, true, but the form in this case is not being submitted through the regular submit button but through a javascript call. (damn phone calls and missed page refresh! :D )

Comment: Would another workaround be to use a button instead of submit, then in serialize, rather than use a submit event use a click event?

Comment: @user1532468 No, `button` won't be serialized it's not input element. [Here's](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) list of elements that can be serialized.

Comment: This is IMHO the correct answer, since you can submit a form using the keyboard, so the button will be not serialized.